# Create an Object inside for loop

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I want to create an object of class inside for loop but i can't figure out what wrong i am doing.
This is my select function.

```
   public function admin_select_all ($table, $rows = '*', $where = null, $order = null)
{
   if(empty($table))
   {
    return false;
   }

   $q = 'SELECT '.$rows.' FROM '.$table;
    if($where != null)
        $q .= ' WHERE '.$where;
    if($order != null)
        $q .= ' ORDER BY '.$order;

    if($this->admin_tableExists($table))
   {
    $stmt = $this->admin_connection->prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if( (!$results) or (empty($results)) ) { 
        return false;
    }
    return $results;
   }


}
```

This is a constructor of  class admin_element

```
    public function __construct($itemId)
{
    global $db_operate;
    $info = $db_operate->admin_select_all ("my_table" ,"id=".$itemId);
    $this->id = $info[0]['id'];
    $this->title = $info[0]['title'];
    $this->seoUrl = $info[0]['seo_url'];
    $this->parentId = $info[0]['parent_id'];
    $this->isMenuItem = $info[0]['menu_item'];
    $this->order = $info[0]['menu_order'];
    $this->htmlId = $info[0]['anchor_unique_html_id'];
}
```

//This is the function inside admin_element where  i want to create an object inside for loop

```
    public static function getRootItems()
{
    global $db_operate;

    $parents = $db_operate->admin_select_all ("my_table");
    $listOfItems = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($parents);$i++)
    {
        $listOfItems[$i] = new admin_element($parents[$i]['id']);
    }
    //var_dump($listOfItems);
    return $listOfItems;
   }
}
```

Now when i create an object with this then i am getting the error undefined id in the constructor, and when i var_dump the array then i get the error's equal to the total length $parent which is my returned array. I don't know what wrong i am doing . I also try it with foreach but still no success.

//With foreach i try it but not able to create and object

```
foreach($parents as $row) {
        $listOfItems[] = array(

        'id' => $row['id']


        );

    }
```

Here when i var_dump the $listOfItems array then it's working well but when i try to instantiate the object then it also fail please some help.If this question is asked before i apologize.

Comment: `$q .= ' WHERE '.$where;` Don't you know [Little Booby Drop Table](https://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: I know that check the function parameter's the $where is coming from there

Comment: You have a syntax error with `id=".$itemId` in `$info = $db->select("my_table" ,id=".$itemId);`

Comment: in foreach you can create object same way (without $i only). Show us full error code

Comment: What does `var_dump($info)` show?

Comment: That syntax error came when i was pasting my code here and i was deleting some personnel records so mistakenly the double code removed. I have edited the question now its ok

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: It seems like you're doing a lot of unnecessary queries. `getRootItems` queries the table for all the rows. Then instead of using those return values when you create `itrom_element` you do another query using the ID. Why don't you just create `itrom_element` with all the data from the returned row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
$listOfItems = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($parents);$i++)
{
    $listOfItems[$i] = new itrom_element($parents[$i]['id']);
}
```

With this:

```
foreach($parents as $parent)
    $listOfItems[]= new itrom_element($parent['id']);
```

Comment: he didnt mention, that there is a syntax error, so its propably editing problem

Comment: No that's not the problem, while pasting my question here i was changing some table names etc so the double quote remove mistakenly. That's ok i have edited it you can check it now

Comment: Main question is how can i create an object of the class inside of the for or foreach loop and what i am doing is it worng or irihgt..some suggestion